# How to include file marked in string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, include

I have a string, where user can add special mark, for example `[include=example_file]` and I would like to include "example_file.php" to the place where the mark is.

User's text can be like:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

[include=contact_form] // here should be contact_form.php included

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
```

I use this, to echo user's text, now:

```
<?php echo $this->view['users_text']; ?>
```

... and new output should be like:

```
<?php
// echo first paragraph
include "contact_form.php";
// echo second paragraph
?>
```

What is the simplest way how to include files finded in those special marks?

Comment: Replace the placeholder with a call for the content. `str_replace('[include=contact_form]', file_get_contents(....), $this->view['users_text'])` or explode on the string and then echo part 1, include file, echo part 2

Comment: str_replace() works for me only when the file does not contain php code, unfortunately

Comment: watch out for *implemented* LFI's `[include=../../../../../etc/passwd]`

Comment: Sure, I simplied this issue. There will be, of course, some kind of control, e.g. in config file will be array with allowed files to include.

Comment: Use method 2 for PHP including. Or use `preg_split` if `contact_form` is variable.

Comment: Yes, the solution below is correct, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful of LFI attacks, but to achieve this, match the placeholder with regex, loop over it, use the value to load the file within a buffer, then replace the placeholder with the buffer.

Like this:

```
<?php
$content = '
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

[include=contact_form] // here should be contact_form.php included

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

[include=cat] // here should be cat.php included
';

// match 
if (preg_match_all('#\[include=(?P<name>.*?)\]#', $content, $includes)) {
    // loop
    foreach($includes['name'] as $include) {
        // buffer
        ob_start();
        //include($include.'.php'); // 
        echo 'I was from '.$include.'.php';
        $buffer = ob_get_clean();

        // replace
        $content = str_replace('[include='.$include.']', $buffer, $content);
    }
}

echo $content;
```

https://3v4l.org/qPqbI